# Jquery Slidetoggle, how to allow to show only one element?

Tags: javascript, html, slidetoggle

This is my html:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        List
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        List 2
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this js:

```
$('ul li ul').hide();

$('ul li').click(function() {
    $(this).children().slideToggle();
});
```

I want to create slidetoggle, for example: when user click "List" and after open this user click List 2 then list one is hiding.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7dxAb/
I want only one open when user click.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('ul li ul').hide();

$('ul li').click(function() {
    var _this = $(this);
    _this.children().slideToggle();

    $('ul > li').not(_this).children('ul').slideUp();
});
```

You hide "ul"s in all ListN elements except one that is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You can `slideUp()` all the other `ul`'s before the `slideToggle()` like this:

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul').slideUp();
    $(this).children().slideToggle();
});
```

I'm not sure if this is the most effecient way tho.

Comment: well, closes, but bug when you expand the lists and clicking again to expand and collapse, here demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7dxAb/4/

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
$('ul li ul').slideUp();
```

to the click event. This will hide the other `ul`s.
The finished code would look like:

```
$('ul li ul').hide();

$('ul li').click(function() {
    $('ul li ul').slideUp();
    $(this).children().slideToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yvPFx/2/

**Edit**: You can use a class to keep track of what is showing.
http://jsfiddle.net/yvPFx/3/

Comment: when a click on the expanded list does not want to roll :/ is on it's way?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('ul li ul').hide();

 $("ul li").click(function () {
     $(this).children().slideToggle("slow", function() {
        //
      });
     $(this).siblings().children().slideUp("slow");
 });
```